# HTTP Request file get contents not working

Tags: php, http, request, file-get-contents, bonita

I'm trying to send a file through rest using HTTP request to BonitaBPM but the file im trying to send comes out empty when i use file get contents and the HTTP request doesn't work obviously due to that

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/upload/Director.png"); 
$data1 = array(
    "caseId"=> $case_id[1],
    "file"=>"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/upload/Director.png",
    "name"=>"doc_invoice",
    "fileName"=> $_FILES['file_attach']['name'],
    "description"=> "Invoice"
);
//Structure of process data to start case
$options1 = array(
    "http" => array(
        "method"  => "POST",
        "header"=>  "POST /bonita/API/bpm/caseDocument  HTTP/1.1\r\n".
            "Host: bonita.libertypr.com\r\n".
            "Cookie: ". $display[1]."\r\n".
            "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
            "Accept: application/json\r\n".
            "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n".
            "Pragma: no-cache\r\n".
            "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n",
        "content" => json_encode($data1)
    )
);
//decode process data and adds document to case
$url1 = "http://bonita.libertypr.com:8081/bonita/API/bpm/caseDocument";
$context1  = stream_context_create($options1);
$result1 = file_get_contents($url1, false, $context1);
$response1 =  json_decode($result1);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to have an extra `)`? Maybe it's closing the array... hard to tell with the indents like that. Have you tried curl instead? Or `var_export($result1);`

Comment: Have you done an http file upload to this script? $_FILES won't be populated unless you do, and your `$data1` will NOT contain the `director.png` file you've fetched - you're embedding the PATH to the file, not the file itself.

Comment: Yes because i send the file through email when i use move uploaded file function and when i check the folder the file is right there.

Comment: How would i embed to the file itself??

Comment: Take a look as this very similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724640/php-post-file-with-file-get-contents

Comment: I've tried but i still get the same error

Comment: You never posted your error. You just said it 'comes out empty'. Please edit your post and include the Error. That's important in posts like this.

Comment: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error but somehow the file appears in bonitasoft but when i download it, it comes up empty

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are authenticated on the Bonita side before calling this API call.
See this link for more details:
http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/rest-api-overview#authentication

If you are not, the Bonita API calls will be rejected.

To analyze a bit further what is causing the issue, you should get your hands on the HTTP request and response sent between your code and Bonita.
To do so, you can capture the HTTP traffic with a tool such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org)

Cheers,

Comment: I have authenticated in bonitasoft and i am able to do multiple requests from a website, the only one causing problems is caseDocument